# Can Azure release pipeline task inline Powershell connecting to MongoDB load(file) method

Tags: mongodb, azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Been working with MDBC powershell module to connect to MongoDB instance in Azure cosmosDB. Need to load a .js file with the code to update the collections..

Example:(mikesSuperHappyJS.js)

```
var collection = 'MikesContext';

   use('HappyMongoDBStuff);
   db[collection].drop();
   db.createCollection(collection);
   db[collection].createIndex({ MarketId: 1 });

db[collection].insert({
"_id": "9875309",
"_t": "MikesContext",
"MikesId": 98457,
"MikesName": "Mike",
"UWGuideLink": "https://mikedopp.com/funnyman.pdf",
"KnowledgeBaseLink": ""
});
```

would love to use

```
 MongoDB "load(file)" or Load(mikesSuperHappyJS.js) to import this very important .js file.
```

However Im not finding a way to do such a thing.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/method/load/

used mdbc to do the powershell module work but cant find a "easy" way to just load the .js file.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **`load()`** seems is a [method in the MongoDB Shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/methods/#native-methods) and not available for MDBC PowerShell module.

To use the **`load()`** method in PowerShell, you can try with the following steps:

1. Download and install MongoDB Shell (**`mongosh.exe`**) on the agent machine.
2. On PowerShell, you first need to run the **`mongosh`** command to connect to your MongoDB deployment.

   ```
   mongosh "{connection string}" -u {username} -p {password}
   ```
3. Then you can run the following command with the **`load()`** method to load and execute the **`.js`** file.

   ```
   load( "path/to/mikesSuperHappyJS.js" )
   ```

For more details, you can see "[**Write Scripts - MongoDB Shell**](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/)".

---